# Runs locally with SQLite, but on Heroku: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

My code runs fine for sqllite locally, but when I push to heroku I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 1: ...LECT  "beeps".* FROM "beeps" WHERE ((widget_id NOT NULL) AND ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "beeps".* FROM "beeps" WHERE ((widget_id NOT NULL) AND (updated_at > '2011-02-06 02:27:59.867809') AND (userphone = '0000000xxxx') AND (beeper
= '0000000zzzz') AND (inbound = 't')) ORDER BY beeps.id DESC LIMIT 1):
```

the ruby code is :

```
Beep.last(:conditions => [ "(widget_id NOT NULL) AND (updated_at > ?) AND (userphone = ?) AND (beeper = ?) AND (inbound = ?)", 5.minutes.ago, aphone, beeper, inboundflag ])
```

By the way, is there any way to structure this query using pure active record, so we can (hopefully) avoid database-specific query strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using SQLLite on Heroku and not MySQL? Either way the query syntax seems a little incorrect. I would modify your query to this:

```
Beep.last(:conditions => [ "(widget_id IS NOT NULL) AND (updated_at > ?) AND (userphone = ?) AND (beeper = ?) AND (inbound = ?)", 5.minutes.ago, aphone, beeper, inboundflag ])
```

If you are using Rails3 you can chain your conditions together like this:

```
Beep.where('widget_id IS NOT NULL)
  .where('updated_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago)
  .where(userphone: aphone)
  .where(beeper: beeper)
  .where(inbound: inboundflag)
  .last
```

Comment: thank you! "xxx NOT NULL" worked fine on sqllite but I see it should have the "IS": "xxx IS NOT NULL"