# Not nil code that works for both sqlite3 and pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, pg

I have a rails app running sqlite3 in development and pg in production, currently running on Heroku. I am getting an error on my heroku app. I have a column called 'archived' which starts out as nil until the user pushes a button, then the current time gets written into the cell. Then all messages where archived != nil is then ordered by most recent.

Below is a portion of my heroku log:

> 2013-05-07T22:00:31.775149+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms
>   2013-05-07T22:00:31.785541+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-05-07T22:00:31.785541+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
>   2013-05-07T22:00:31.785541+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ... "messages".* FROM "messages"  WHERE (archived <> '') ORDER ...
>   2013-05-07T22:00:31.785541+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
>   2013-05-07T22:00:31.785541+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages"  WHERE (archived <> '') ORDER BY archived desc LIMIT 10):

This tells me that the issue is this line of code from my controller:

> ```
> @archived_messages = Message.where("archived <> ''").limit(10).order('archived desc')
> ```

What should I change this code to so that it works in both sqlite3 and pg?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

> ```
> @archived_messages = Message.where("archived IS NOT NULL").limit(10).order('archived desc')
> ```

source: [Runs locally with SQLite, but on Heroku: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911180/runs-locally-with-sqlite-but-on-heroku-pgerror-error-syntax-error-at-or-nea)